# Lock user out if they try the wrong private key (passwordless authentication ) 3 times

Tags: ssh

I am using ssh keypairs for authentication. I want to lock an account if the user tries to use the wrong private key 3 times. How can i achieve this?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: You should look into `fail2ban`. I think it might offer what you're looking for.

Comment: Jakuje , because i am using ssh-key pair for login  & i also want  a/c locking facility  with that.